# Seminal works in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, references

I'm compiling a list of 7 seminal works in deep learning to work on during 14 week semester course. I'd appreciate if you suggested papers for the list. I'm looking for the papers that impacted the field in a major way. The only constraint is that the paper must be reproducible, i.e. based on freely available data and the codes are described in sufficient detail. It really is not much of a constrain, actually.

For instance, this paper would be in my list:   Krizhevsky, A., Sutskever, I. and Hinton, G. E., ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks, NIPS 2012: Neural Information Processing Systems, Lake Tahoe, Nevada

Comment: I don't mean to limit the field to image processing by the above example, of course. Though I'd probably exclude anything related to Netflix recommendations. :) Someone needs top tell them try backtesting - their movie recommendations to me are as good as random picks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you give an example of a paper that "revolutionized" the field of *image classification*, I would add examples of papers that had similar impact on *image segmentation*:

1. Long, J., Shelhamer, E. and Darrell, T., 2015. *Fully convolutional networks for semantic segmentation*. In Proceedings of the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition (pp. 3431-3440) [(pdf)](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Long_Fully_Convolutional_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf)
2. Ronneberger, O., Fischer, P. and Brox, T., 2015, October. *U-net: Convolutional networks for biomedical image segmentation*. In International Conference on Medical image computing and computer-assisted intervention (pp. 234-241). Springer, Cham. [(arxiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597)

They both are relatively easy to grasp and present their results on publicly accessible datasets.